# Calling parent window method from Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, same-origin-policy

I know this is an issue of cross-browser communication or same origin policy and browser will not allow such communication.

I need a work around this use-case.I have a parent page in HTTP and from there i am submitting the form to HTTPS, my requirement is not to move away from the page and the form is opening up in an overlay.

This is my current JSP settings

```
<form:form action="https://localhost:9002/myApp/springSecurity/login" class="login-form error-info"  id="loginForm"  method="post" commandName="loginForm" target="guestFrame">

 <iframe width="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="guestFrame" >
```

from the server i am sending java-script in the response to be append on the Iframe, this is the java-script being sent from the server

```
<html><body>"+ "<script type=\"text/javascript\">parent.handleResponse('error',securityLoginStatus.getLoginFailedException());</script>"+ "</body></html>")
```

i have already defined a method in the parent window namely `handle-response` but i am getting following error in browser

```
Permission denied to access property 'handleResponse'
```

i even tried with `parent.wwindow.handleResponse` but getting same error.
is there any way i can communicate with the parent window from the Iframe ?

Comment: I assume `parent.wwindow` is a typo too.

Comment: yes, this is just a typo :) in actual code its `parent`

Comment: Try with `window.top.handleResponse`.

Comment: I have done something similar using jquery and I normally use `top.window`. I normally use it as a selector, so it may need to be tweaked.

Comment: @Furqan: i am not sure about this approach. sorry being less aware of it. i am more of server side person that UI :(

Comment: @kwelch: can you share that? and was that done for cross domain?

Comment: Try with window.top.handleResponse. in your client script.

Comment: @Furqan: i already tried that already its giving same issue

Comment: Here is what I did `$("#tabs", window.top.document).prepend(filesImg);`. The filesImg is just a local variable containing html. This may not help with the cross domain. I have also used this line with jQuery, `jQuery.support.cors = true;` but it was for AJAX calls that are cross domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said before there is no way around to avoid cross origin permission denied unless both html origin and destiny be under `http://localhost:9002` domain.

For ease, I recommend using the http communication with javascript/json/jsonp docs. 
You could try jQuery with something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendPost () {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'https://localhost:9002/myApp/springSecurity/login',
      data: $("#guestFrame").serialize(),
      error: function(data, status) {
        // alert('Error ' + status);
      }
    });
}
function handleResponse(obj) {
    if (obj.type==="error") {
        alert("Error: " + obj.mssg);
    }
}
</script>

<form ...>
 ...
 <input type="submit" value="send" onclick="sendPost();return(false)"/>
</form>
```

And in order to avoid the CORS restriction, `https://localhost:9002/myApp/springSecurity/login` html response must be a javascript code and include
the following headers:

```
<% 
response.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-javascript");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
%>
```

Javascript example response which will be able to call "handleResponse" of its parent caller:

```
handleResponse({'type':'error', 'mssg': 'your_login_failed_exception'});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a framework such as http://easyxdm.net/wp/ to make cross domain calls